# react export Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have these file and folder.

```
App.js
modules/
  user/
    index.js
    list.js
```

In list.js I have `export default (props) => (...)`

In index.js I have `export UserList from './list';`

And in App.js I have `import { UserList } from './modules/user';`

Is there something wrong there? Because I got

```
./src/modules/user/index.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected { (1:7)
> 1 | export UserList from './list';
```

But I don't see what's wrong here? Help!

Edit: Here's more details of my list.js file, but I don't think it makes a difference because the error is in index.js

```
import React from 'react';
// more import
export default (props) => (
  <List {...props}>
    ...
  </List>
);
```

Comment: Can you share your index.js or list.js? There is a clearly syntax error.

Comment: @OzgurGUL: "export UserList from './list';" is literally the whole content of my /modules/user/index.js

Comment: First you must import it AFAIK: `import UserList from './list; 
export default UserList`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Ah, good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I see you are exporting the component directly which belongs to another file without importing it.

The way you are doing it is a [ES8 Proposal](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-more-export-from)

In ES6, you could export the component as

```
 export {default as UserList} from './list'
```

and then import as

```
import { UserList } from './modules/user';
```

Comment: Verified locally, nice one.

Comment: That works! Interesting. I got the idea of my above code from here: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/src/rest/index.js

It works there but not for me.

Comment: Not sure how it works if at all it works for the OP in the Github repository. Clearly that is a ES8 syntax which I am not sure is available yet to use

Comment: They're using babel with `stage-0`, perhaps that's it.

Comment: In case you have multiple imports in the file and you want to export all in one object, use export {UserList, otherComponent}? With this, you don't have to use the default.

Answer (score 5):

**For Babel 6 users**

add babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions plugin to your **.babelrc** like this:

```
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions",
    "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
  ]
```

and then run to the following install the plugins

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-export-extensions
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs
```

After this, export of modules will work in the following way from index.js:

```
export simpleRestClient from './simple';
export jsonServerRestClient from './jsonServer';
export * from './types';
```

For those using earlier babel versions, simply use the commonjs module.

Answer (score 0):

I added `<script type="module" src="/Aapp.js"></script>` in inside of `body` section of `public/index.html`. It worked for me.
Please refer this [blog](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/vite-how-to-fix-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export).

I used node version `18.12.1` and react version `17.0.2`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- ✅ set this script’s type to `module` -->
    <script type="module" src="/Aapp.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```